# Change nodata value from -99999 to -9999

Tags: qgis, raster, r, reclassify, nodata

I read many threads here to change the nodata value of my raster to desired value - in my case from -99999 to -9999. It seems I can not use spider or anything similliar as I do not have admin rights. I also tried reclassify (SAGA) but when I run it, the module required me to fill all fields (single, range, simple table) although I picked the single method to use because it seems I have to choose at least one method. In the bottom part of the Reclassify box I set the nodata to desired value but its failed. Report said the range and simple table data must be filled.

Then I found that QGIS 2.18 is suitable for that and it does the work, however when I run the same Reclassify in QGIS 2.18 I got following report

> > 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details

Can anyone please navigate me to change the nodata somehow regardsless its QGIS or for instance R?

Comment: Not sure, but how about `NAvalue(your_raster_object) <- -9999` ? ... or you mighty be struggling to replace the value.. like `r[r == -99999] <- -9999`...

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the piping advice from @Kazuhito but alternately, pipe in NA ie., `r[r == -99999] <- NA`. This is the native R no data value. When you then use `raster::writeRaster` the no data will parsed to the correct output format value. This is safer than forcing a no data value such as -9999 (which is an ESRI convention). If you say, write a geoTiff, specifying a nodata value as -9999 will cause the NA value to be parsed incorrectly because the functions does not know what this value represents so, will output it as a real vlaue.

You could also use the `mvFlag = -99999` argument in `rgdal::readGDAL` to specify the NA value and skip having to pipe a value. I would recommend then coercing using `raster::raster` and then using `raster::writeRaster` as it is simpler that working through all of the augments of `rgdal::writeGDAL`.

Comment: Does the approach you've suggested work for georeferenced raster also? I followed both suggestions of You and Kazuhito and set the value to -9999, however when I upload the raster to QGIS and view the information, scroll down to the bottom where the NAvalue is displayed it states the value -3.4e+38? Why it does not states the value -9999? The code is

```install.packages("raster")
install.packages('rgdal')
install.packages('sp')
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
x <- raster("Pokus.tif")
NAvalue(x) <- -9999
NAvalue(x)
writeRaster(x, "pokusNA", format = "GTiff")```

Comment: When I then inspect the generated raster for NAvalue with NAvalue(x) it states -inf. Why not -9999?